# PHP - Store XML file onto server

Tags: php

*I am new to `PHP` and I can't seem to find code snippets for storing posted data onto the server `PHP` is running on.*

**HOST :**

I am using `Xmapp/Apache` to create a local server, as seen below:
[image]

**GOAL :**

The goal is to send a post request attaching a `XML` string as content to `POST.php` and the `PHP` script will parse the content into `XML` and store the `.xml` file into `./XML Files` directory

Here is a markup of what the code would be:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["XML"]))
    {

        //put .xml file into server directory ./XML Files

        echo "success";
    }
    else echo "error";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [simplexml_load_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) to create [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and then call [asXML method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) on it to write the data to the file:

```
if (isset($_POST["XML"])) {

    //put .xml file into server directory ./XML Files

    $simpleXMLElement = simplexml_load_string($_POST["XML"]);
    $simpleXMLElement->asXML('./XML Files/filename.xml');

    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```